# form submission with ajax error messages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm new to ajax concept. Here i'm trying to insert the user details(signup form) into the database. it inserted the datas into the db succesfully. But, ajax is my problem.

1) i didn't get any error message if form fields are empty. you can see my below codes i've done validation on post.php page. but, it doesn't return the error values. 2) it stores the empty values into database. 3) if datas stored successfully i want to get the success message & if datas failed to store in db i want to get the error message. How should i do these all things?

**Ajax.js**

```
$(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
              if(msg=='error_n')
              {
                  $("#e_name").html('Name required');                    
              }
              if(msg=='error_m')
              {
                   $("#e_mobile").html('Mobile required');
              }

              //success and error alert
              if(data="inserted")
              {
                alert("insertion success");
              }
              else
              {
                alert("falid to insert into database");
              }
            }
          });
         e.preventDefault();
        });
      });
```

**Post.php**

```
<?php

    include_once('config.php');

    $name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $mobile = trim($_POST["mobile"]);

    if($name == "")
    {
        echo 'error_n';
    }
    if($mobile == "")
    {
        echo 'error_m';
    }

    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sample ( Name, Mobile ) VALUES ( ?, ? )");
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->bindParam('1', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('2', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        'Query failed to insert into database' .$e->getMEssage();
    }

?>
```

**Homepage.php**

```
<p>register <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>

<div id="light" class="white_content">
  <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
   <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="form" value="values" />
      name : <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><span id="e_name"></span> <br />
      mobile : <input name="mobile" id="mobile" type="text" /><span id="e_mobile"></span> <br />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

After your error messages are returned, you need to stop the script execution. Your current code still tries to add the values and hence overrides your custom error messages. Most probably then your PHP returns your exception message and which is not what your JavaScript is expecting.

```
if($name == "")
{
    echo 'error_n';
    die(); // Stop here
}
if($mobile == "")
{
    echo 'error_m';
    die(); // Stop here
}
```

Also add `echo 'inserted';`  when your database insert is successful.

Comment: now its not stored the empty values in db. thats ok. thanks... but, display success and failure message is one of my problem here. i didn't get the success and failure messages properly. it always alert 'insertion success' when empty fields are submit into db. if user submit the empty datas it should show the required values. but it didn't..

Comment: That behavior is not possible with that code. It should return  `error_n` and that will be caught by javascript. Can you check in firebug what value is being returned by PHP to JavaScript when you leave something empty?